# How to extend String to add new unapply function for using it in extracting?

Tags: scala

I want to use a Scala extractor to match my custom type with a `String` (in that specific order, not `String` to `Scala`). Here is my code:

```
class Scala

object Scala {
  def apply(s: String) = new Scala
  def unapply(sc: Scala) = Some("Scala")
}

class ExtendedString(s: String) {
  def unapply(sc: Scala): Option[String] = {
    Some(s)
  }
}

implicit def str2Scala(s: String): ExtendedString = {
  new ExtendedString(s)
}

Scala match {
  case "abc" => println("Aha!")
  case "def" => println("Yeah!")
  case "scala" => println("Scala!")
}
```

But it does not work. I get an error:

```
Error:(20, 9) type mismatch;
 found   : String("abc")
 required: A$A109.this.Scala.type
  case "abc" => println("Aha!")
       ^
```

How can I fix it to make extractor work?

*PS*

My original idea was to provide an implicit converter to extend `String` class with `ExtendedString` class and then to implement `unapply` method there to make extraction possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enrich PartialFunction with unapply functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182235/enrich-partialfunction-with-unapply-functionality)

Comment: No, I don't think they are the same questions. I'm trying to match a custom type to string. A String class does not have `unapply` function to get my custom type.

Comment: You've tried to use implicit conversions in match which is not something scala works like. Scala match expression is not a scala generic expression, and implicits don't work there. It is explained in that question. On how to do that properly, see @Dylan answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need whatsoever for implicits if all you want is an extractor.

To define an extractor, you make an `object` with an `unapply` method. E.g.

```
object MyExtractor {
  def unapply(value: ValueBeingMatched): Option[ExtractedValue] = { ... }
}
```

Then you match a value using the extractor

```
val myValue: ValueBeingMatched = ...
myValue match {
  case MyExtractor(extractedValue) => println(s"I got $extractedValue!")
}
```

If you want your extractor to come back with multiple values, the unapply should return an option of tuple:

```
object MyExtractor {
  def unapply(value: ValueBeingMatched): Option[(ResultType1, ResultType2, ...)] = { ... }
}

val myValue: ValueBeingMatched = ...
myValue match {
  case MyExtractor(result1, result2, ...) => ...
}
```

I'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish from your example code, so I'll make an example that maybe is relevant for you.

Let's say you make a custom `Point` class:

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
```

And you want to be able to extract points from a `String`. In this case, the `ValueBeingMatched` is a `String`, and the `ExtractedValue` is a `Point`. I'll also define the extractor in the `Point` object. As for functionality, let's assume that a string like `"12,8"` corresponds to a `Point(12, 8)`.

```
object Point {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Point] = {
    val parts = s.split(",")
    // this is just example code, so I won't handle failures,
    // but if it did fail, you'd return a None instead of Some
    Some(Point(parts(0).toInt, parts(1).toInt))
  }
}
```

Now that it's defined, you can match strings using the `Point` extractor:

```
val s = "3,4"
s match {
  case Point(p) => // p is actually an instance of Point
}
```

---

*edit to respond to feedback:*

In order to match directly to a string, the value being matched must already *be* a String. So one way would be to add a converter method e.g.

```
instanceOfMyType.convertToString match {
  case "abc" => println("Aha!")
}
```

Or you would have to write an extractor to allow

```
instanceOfMyType match {
  case Extracted("abc") => println("Aha!")
}
```

Comment: My goal was to make something different. I was trying to match not a string to custom type, but the opposite case: custom type to string.

Comment: `MyType match {  case "abc" => println("Aha!") }`

Comment: (I've added a bit to my answer in response to your comments)