# How to add extension method to a singleton object in scala 2?

Tags: scala, object, pattern-matching, extension-methods, implicit

I've stumbled upon [this thread](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/allow-to-match-on-values-type-in-interpolated-string-pattern-matching/5507) and there @prolativ provided some fancy scala 3 syntax for creating extension methods for objects

```scala
extension (int: Int.type)
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = s.toIntOption
```

But this got me thinking if there is a way to do something similar in scala 2?

I've tried

```scala
implicit class IntOps(s: Int.type) {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = s.toIntOption
}
```

Which seemed just scala 2 translation, but it wont compile with error `object Int is not a case class, nor does it have a valid unapply/unapplySeq member`.

***UPD***
In case of pattern matching there is a way to do this - just add new object and match it:

```scala
object IntOps {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = s.toIntOption
}
```

but the question remains - how to add extension methods to object?

Comment: `Int.type` is the right way to add extension methods to the companion object of the type `Int` - It just seems you can't add `unapply` as an extension in **Scala 2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implicit class is a correct way to add extension method to an object

```
implicit class IntOps(obj: Int.type) {
  def parse(s: String): Option[Int] = s.toIntOption
}

Int.parse("123") // Some(123)
```

And `unapply` can be added in the same way

```
implicit class IntOps(obj: Int.type) {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = s.toIntOption
}

Int.unapply("123") // Some(123)
```

Just this will have no impact on pattern matching

```
"123" match {
  case Int(i) => ??? // doesn't compile: object Int is not a case class, nor does it have a valid unapply/unapplySeq member
}
```

The place where Scala 2 compiler throws `object Int is not a case class, nor does it have a valid unapply/unapplySeq member` is here:
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/PatternTypers.scala#L121-L122

```
else if (!reallyExists(member))
  CaseClassConstructorError(fun, s"${fun.symbol} is not a case class, nor does it have a valid unapply/unapplySeq member")
```

This is based on symbols (kind of `typeOf[Int.type].decl(TermName("unapply"))` in `scala-reflect` terms). Implicit conversions (extension methods) are not checked here.

This is modified in Scala 3: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.2.2/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/typer/Applications.scala#L1291-L1341 The compiler tries to typecheck `x.unapply` and this includes implicit conversions.

By the way, when Scala 2 compiler decides whether to generate `unapply` in the companion object of a **case** class (`Int` wasn't a case class) the compiler doesn't check extension methods either

[How can I view the code that Scala uses to automatically generate the apply function for case classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999247/how-can-i-view-the-code-that-scala-uses-to-automatically-generate-the-apply-func)

```
case class MyClass(i: Int)

MyClass(42) match {
  case MyClass(i) => println(i) // 42
}
```

```
case class MyClass(i: Int)
object MyClass {
  def unapply(mc: MyClass): Option[Int] = Some(100)
}

MyClass(42) match {
  case MyClass(i) => println(i) // 100
}
```

```
case class MyClass(i: Int)

implicit class MyClassCompanionOps(mc: MyClass.type) {
  def unapply(mc: MyClass): Option[Int] = Some(100)
}

MyClass(42) match {
  case MyClass(i) => println(i) // 42
}
```

And this behavior is the same in Scala 3.

---

[How to extend String to add new unapply function for using it in extracting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225248/how-to-extend-string-to-add-new-unapply-function-for-using-it-in-extracting)

[enrich PartialFunction with unapply functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182235/enrich-partialfunction-with-unapply-functionality)