# How to pattern match on the types of list elements

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I would like to pattern match on a list of objects based on their types.
But specifying the pattern as `case x: List[ObjectType]` does not seem to work.

Take for example this program.

```
sealed trait A
case class B() extends A
case class C() extends A

def func(theList: List[A]) = theList match
{
    case listOfB: List[B] => println("All B's")
    case listOfC: List[C] => println("All C's")
    case _ => println("Somthing else")
}

func(List(C(), C(), C())) // prints: "All B's"
```

Although the list only contains C's and the case pattern specifies a list of B's, the match statement recognises it as a list of B's?

I know I can check each element of the list like this:

```
case listOfA: List[A] if listOfA.forall{case B() => true case _ => false} => println("All B's")
```

But it's more cumbersome and I have to specify that it is indeed a list of B's (`listOfA.asInstanceOf[List[B]]`) when I try to use it.

How can I do this in a smarter / better way?

Comment: You can not do this because of type erasure. The information inside a type constructor gets erased once the program is compiled so every list becomes `List[_]` thus always matching the first case

Comment: Don't do this, type checks like this are a code smell. You may use a **typeclass** instead.

Comment: @sinanspd Firstly, type erasure can be switched off (type tags etc.). Secondly, OP's code with `listOfA.forall...` does do what he wants. The question is how to make this less cumbersome.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `listOfA.forall{case B() => true case _ => false}` is not type check. `List[A]` in `case listOfA: List[A] if listOfA.forall...` can be just removed. How type class will help with checking that all runtime values of `List[A]` are `B`?

Comment: @DmytroMitin right my bad, didn't see it was an ADT.  Yeah so it depends if OP have a List of Bs at compile time and want to do something different with it, then a **Typeclass** would help. But, if the data come at runtime then yeah, the only thing he can do is those expensive `forall`, to make them less verbose it may use some **extractors** to hide the logic but still would be slow. Other alternatives would be storing that information on a wrapper class something like `final case class ListHolder[T <: A](as: List[A], type: String)` or whatever, another approach would be redesign the solution

Comment: Could you write an example (in an answer) of how I would use a typeclass for this problem?
Both to mark it as the correct answer, but also because after reading about  typeclasses, i'm not quit sure how to do it.

Comment: @SørenHN I once wrote about [**Polymorphism**](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4) in Scala, maybe that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have at compile time a `List[B]` or a `List[C]` and you want to manipulate them in a different way, you can use a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html).

Something like this:

```
trait MyTypeClass[T] {
  def process(data: List[T]): String
}

sealed trait A extends Product with Serializable
final case class B() extends A
final case class C() extends A
object A extends ALowerPriority {
  implicit final val AllOfB: MyTypeClass[B] =
    (_: List[B]) => "All B's"
  
  implicit final val AllOfC: MyTypeClass[C] =
    (_: List[C]) => "All C's"
}

trait ALowerPriority {
  implicit final val Mixed: MyTypeClass[A] =
    (_: List[A]) => "Somenthing else"
}

def func[T](theList: List[T])
          (implicit ev: MyTypeClass[T]): Unit =
  println(ev.process(data = theList))
```

Which works like this:

```
val bs = List(B(), B(), B())
val cs = List(C(), C(), C())
val mixed = List(C(), B(), C())

func(bs) // All B's
func(cs) // All C's
func(mixed) // Something else
```

*Note: You would need to think what would be the interface to expose on your typeclass, so you can write generic functions but that behave differently according to the underlying type.*

---

However, remember **typeclasses** are selected at compile time and using only the types. So, if you have a compile time value of type `List[A]` even if it is full of `Bs` it will pick `"Something else"`:

```
val as: List[A] = List(B(), B(), B())
func(as) // Something else
```

---

You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/tpDVqLM3Qvqfofo5bPFjHw/2).

Comment: By the way, type class approach can work even at runtime (so that for `val as: List[A] = List(B(), B(), B())` `func` will print `"All B's"`). See type class `Typeable` in Shapeless. Just its instances for lists should be defined trickier (using runtime reflection) https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeable.scala#L235-L250 I added code snippet with `Typeable`/`TypeCase` to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try custom extractors to make pattern matching less cumbersome

```
object AllB {
  def unapply(listOfA: List[A]): Boolean = 
    listOfA.forall { case B() => true; case _ => false }
}
object AllC {
  def unapply(listOfA: List[A]): Boolean = 
    listOfA.forall { case C() => true; case _ => false }
}

def func(theList: List[A]) = theList match {
  case AllB() => println("All B's")
  case AllC() => println("All C's")
  case _      => println("Something else")
}

func(List(B(), B(), B()))    // All B's
func(List[A](B(), B(), B())) // All B's
func(List(C(), C(), C()))    // All C's
func(List(C(), B(), C()))    // Something else
```

or

```
import cats.implicits._

object AllB {
  def unapply(listOfA: List[A]): Option[List[B]] = 
    listOfA.traverse { case b@B() => Some(b); case _ => None }
}
object AllC {
  def unapply(listOfA: List[A]): Option[List[C]] = 
    listOfA.traverse { case c@C() => Some(c); case _ => None }
}

def func(theList: List[A]) = theList match {
  case AllB(listOfB) => println("All B's")
  case AllC(listOfC) => println("All C's")
  case _             => println("Something else")
}

func(List(B(), B(), B()))    // All B's
func(List[A](B(), B(), B())) // All B's
func(List(C(), C(), C()))    // All C's
func(List(C(), B(), C()))    // Something else
```

Or you can define a single class to create all necessary extractors and remove code repetitions

```
class All[SubT: ClassTag] {
  def unapply[T >: SubT](listOfA: List[T]): Option[List[SubT]] = 
    listOfA.traverse { case x: SubT => Some(x); case _ => None }
}

object AllB extends All[B]
object AllC extends All[C]
// val AllB = new All[B]
// val AllC = new All[C]

def func(theList: List[A]) = theList match {
  case AllB(listOfB) => println("All B's")
  case AllC(listOfC) => println("All C's")
  case _             => println("Something else")
}

func(List(B(), B(), B()))    // All B's
func(List[A](B(), B(), B())) // All B's
func(List(C(), C(), C()))    // All C's
func(List(C(), B(), C()))    // Something else
```

I guess, the simplest is to use Shapeless

```
import shapeless.TypeCase

val AllB = TypeCase[List[B]]
val AllC = TypeCase[List[C]]

def func(theList: List[A]) = theList match {
  case AllB(listOfB) => println("All B's")
  case AllC(listOfC) => println("All C's")
  case _             => println("Something else")
}

func(List(B(), B(), B()))    // All B's
func(List[A](B(), B(), B())) // All B's
func(List(C(), C(), C()))    // All C's
func(List(C(), B(), C()))    // Something else
```

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#type-safe-cast

In Shapeless type class `Typeable` is defined. Just its instances for lists are defined a little trickier than in **@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez**'s answer (namely, using runtime reflection)

> ```
> /** Typeable instance for `Traversable`.    
>  *  Note that the contents be will tested for conformance to the element type. */  
> implicit def genTraversableTypeable[CC[X] <: Iterable[X], T]
>   (implicit mCC: ClassTag[CC[_]], castT: Typeable[T]): Typeable[CC[T] with Iterable[T]] =
>   // Nb. the apparently redundant `with Iterable[T]` is a workaround for a
>   // Scala 2.10.x bug which causes conflicts between this instance and `anyTypeable`.
>   new Typeable[CC[T]] {
>     def cast(t: Any): Option[CC[T]] =
>       if(t == null) None
>       else if(mCC.runtimeClass isInstance t) {
>         val cc = t.asInstanceOf[CC[Any]]
>         if(cc.forall(_.cast[T].isDefined)) Some(t.asInstanceOf[CC[T]])
>         else None
>       } else None
>     def describe = s"${safeSimpleName(mCC)}[${castT.describe}]"
>   }
> ```

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeable.scala#L235-L250

Also see *Ways to pattern match generic types in Scala* https://gist.github.com/jkpl/5279ee05cca8cc1ec452fc26ace5b68b

Comment: Funny that I was writing about extractors at the same time that you posted an answer using them :) - The downside _(as I said in my other comment)_ is that this is still slow, but probably the only way.

Comment: _"I fear no man, but that thing (**Shapeless**), it scares me"_ :) - pretty cool addition, but probably at that point, the extractors would be _"easier"_ to understand and use.